# Official 7" Display not functioning correctly

Tags: power-supply, display, screen

The first day I had the display, it booted fine, loaded and worked just fine, however I had a little bit of flickering from the screen. Today I tried to boot again and the screen comes up with some funky rainbow lines. This is not the display that the Pi does when it doesn't boot. It has very thin multicolored lines across the screen. My Pi is functioning properly, any suggestions? I'm thinking maybe power supply issues but I can't test that until tomorrow.

Comment: I'd start with reseating or replacing the ribbon cable and confirmation the Pi is working by disconnecting the LCD and using the HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the power connection, but that's something that you would see immediate, because you will notice a loose wire.

My first idea is the display-connection. Notice that you have a moving part in one of the two connections 
(sorry I cant remmember if it was on the Pi or on the screen). Make sure you pulled the moving part away when you insert the DSI Ribbon cable, and push it until you hear a 'click' when the ribbon is connected.

[image]